# Instance id in cloud foundry is not a guid?

Tags: .net-core, cloud-foundry, steeltoe

I tried to use Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration.CloudFoundryCore version 3.1.0 in a .NET Core 3.1 project. The value returned by "vcap:application:instance_id" was like this "e1e95ea2-4531-4be9-77f5-1dd2", which is not a valid guid, is this expected behavior?

Comment: Any time I've looked, Instance_Id looks like a Guid, but I don't know offhand if there is any guarantee there. Steeltoe treats that property as a string though, is it causing any problems for you?

Comment: My assumption was that it's a Guid and I tried to parse it as a Guid. It doesn't cause any problem, I was just surprised to find out that it's not. I also didn't find any documentation stating it's not a Guid.